# Does $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k! }{n!}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to know if $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k! }{n!}$$ converge as $n \to \infty$. I know that the sequence is bounded by one since $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k! \leq (n-1)(n-1)!$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How formally do you need to demonstrate it? Because I'm sure WolframAlpha will tell you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take your inequality one step further,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k!=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}k!+(n-1)!\leq (n-2)(n-2)!+(n-1)!
\end{align*}
you can show your sequence is bounded above by $\frac{2}{n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k! }{n!} = \frac{1!+2!+...+(n-1)!}{n!} \leq \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{(n-1)(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{n-1}{n} < 1$$

Comment: so the sequence is increasing and bounded.

Comment: @dust05 Why would it be increasing ?

Comment: first i thought it is trivial, but it is not. @Ayoub

Comment: and it appears to be decreasing for first $n$'s. sorry for false assertion

Comment: If you are referring to the sequence $x_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k! }{n!}$, it is not necessarily so. We showed a bound, the moment we used the $\leq$ sign we no longer are dealing with the same sequence so we can't look at terms to the right of the sign to determine the trend of the original sequence.

Comment: In fact, when $n$ is sufficiently large the sequence is monotonically decreasing and converges to the value $1/n$ with a deviation from this value of the order $1/n^2$.